# Search Bar in Navigation Bar titleView pops out of UINavigationItem on orientation change?

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have added a search bar to the titleView of my Navigation Bar. 
[image]

It looks good except for when the orientation changes.  For whatever reason the search bar is changing position. It's as if the search bar is popping out or is too big for the Navigation Bar all of a sudden.
[image]

Has anyone else had this problem and knows how to fix it? I am using storyboards and was wondering if there is a setting that I am missing or something. Here is my code:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"];

    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height)];
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];

    UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 260.0, 44.0)];
    searchBarView.autoresizingMask = 0;

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarView.frame];
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    [searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
}
```

Comment: Instead of shoving things into the nav bar I would disable the nav bar on the view and add the items to the root view itself.

Comment: Is that the only way around it?  It seems as if the Navigation Bar is shorter in landscape orientation.